# When to use "circa" or "ungefähr"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Both words can be translated as "**approximately**".

Is there any rule/guidance as to the usage of *circa* and *ungefähr*?

I have heard *circa* being used more often and when there are numbers involved (and particularly when dates are involved).

Please give some examples to clarify the difference or similarity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>*Ungefähr* has approximately three times more entries than *circa* in a corpus ([Wortschatz-Portal Uni Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/)).</strike>

*Circa*, *zirka* and *ca.* together indeed have more than three times as much entries than *ungefähr* in a corpus ([Wortschatz-Portal Uni Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/)).

That said, the use of *circa* is restricted to numbers though. I can't think of any example where it wouldn't sound off, when not referring to any numbers. An example where its usage is incorrect.

> *Das ist circa mein Problem.

In this example, in contrast, the word *ungefähr* fits perfectly.

Other examples for *ungefähr*:

> Das kommt nicht von ungefähr.
>   Das ist ungefähr das gleiche.
>   Sie waren ungefähr gleich begabt.
>   Eine ungefähre Angabe würde genügen.

In any of these examples *circa* doesn't sound well. However, when referring to a number again, you can take *circa* even if this number is not mentioned.

> Es kamen circa gleich viele Leute.
>   Er ist circa gleich groß.

Still, I'd tend to use *ungefähr* in those sentences though.

As a conclusion: the claim that *circa* is used more often than *ungefähr* is true. You should remember that *circa* is restricted to numbers. As *ungefähr* has a broader area of usages and is still less frequent, I think *circa* is indeed almost solely used for numbers.
This is in contrast to my original assumption that usages are equally frequent. The corpus proved me wrong on this. Still, this outcome surprises me. I'd be interested into data for colloquial only; unfortunately, I don't know any sources for that.

Comment: Nice explanation and thanks for the link to the Leipzig uni portal.

Comment: The first example is nonsense: "Das ist ungefähr mein Problem." The second example should be treated separatly as it is a fixed saying. The third and forth example could be used with `circa` but aren't. The fifth example couldn't be used with `circa` at all, because `circa` is an adverb, not an adjective. Sixth and seventh example are like third and forth.

Comment: `Zirka` (more German form) is more often used than `circa`. If you take results for both, it's pretty similar (< 30% difference). But you're correct with everything else.

Comment: @bwoebi: I'm German but I wouldn't write `zirka` instead of `circa`. Also I don't think I've ever seen it written that way until today.

Comment: @UliGerhardt I'm from Luxembourg. I always write `zirka` and would say that I'd read it more often than `circa`. Must be personal preference. (Though I see `circa` often used as abbreviation, `ca.`, but rarely written out.)

Comment: How does "quasi" fit into the above? In Pons, it states that it means "almost" or "more or less". Could quasi also be used in the above examples?

Comment: @user5105: "quasi" could be used in most of the sentences. But most times it doesn't make sense to use it. I would translate it to "for all practical purposes".

Comment: @bwoebi Thank you very much for this hint. You are right. Checking the corpus again, including *zirka* and *ca.*, showed that this word is far more frequent than *ungefähr* and I stand corrected. My initial assumption proved wrong.

Comment: In some cases "in etwa" can also be used (like "das ist in etwa das gleiche")

Comment: @toscho if you are still on a "circa" wave, "das ist ungefähr mein Problem" is indeed nonsense. But if you imagine a situation where somebody has told a story and finishes this sentence, in the sense of "so ungefähr ist mein Problem" ("this covers the problem, more or less"), it does make sense. I think it is an important case where the two words have different usage, even if it is counted as an idiom.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has mentioned the spelling "cirka" so far.

Comment: @rumtscho Oh, you are right. Different stress yields a sensical result in that sentence.

Comment: @Toscho: I would never use circa in the third and forth example as you mentioned. For me it plainly sounds wrong to use circa with "gleich". These two words just don't fit together. I can't right now come up with an example were I would use circa with anything else then numbers or times/dates.

Comment: @MrLister This one is used much more rarely and not sure if it's worth a mention in the answer.

Comment: "Das wird ca. November, mit einer Antwort" scheint mir eine gültige Aussage ohne dass November eine Nummer wäre. "Das liegt ca. zwischen Paris und Reimes" ebenfalls. In anderen Fällen ("ca. Kobaltblau"? - eher nicht. "ungefähr Kobaltblau"? prima.) ist circa zumindest äußerst ungebräuchlich.

Comment: @userunknown Any of your examples sounds odd to me using "circa". Actually, these are perfect examples where–in my book–you must use "ungefähr". That said, I'm already convinced of that this is really differently considered in different parts of Germany (and Austria and Swiss).

Answer (score 5):

To my experience Swiss Written German (which is about the same as actual High German just with many specific "Swiss" expressions and no sz) uses "circa" or its short form "ca." way more often than our Northern neighbours do, also as a replacement for "ungefähr":

> "Das ist ca. die Stelle." - "That's about the place."
>   "Das ist ca. die Reaktion, die ich erwartet hatte." - "That's about the reaction I expected."
>   "Das sind ca. die Leute, die wir brauchen" - "That's about the people we need"

I don't know how interesting this is for you, but I mostly wanted to point out, that it also depends on which German speaking regions you take into account.

Comment: Note that I was proved wrong on my initial assumption. According to the corpus *circa* is used more often as I thought–even in Germany. –– Interestingly, your first example doesn't sound that bad to me. The other two are an absolute disaster to my ear, although the last one refers to a number (number of people) and should be valid according to my answer. I really get the feeling the use of these words varies a lot depending on the region you're living.

Comment: I live near swiss border and your answer is helpful to me. Thanks for adding another dimension to the discussion.

Comment: I think, much of Swiss German sounds horrible to German ears :D
Anyways, it's definitely a question of your dialect and therefor the region you come from and live in.
All the examples are totally fine to Swiss people, maybe less to other German speakers.
The last one by the way doesn't refer to a number of people, but to their quality. My translation is not good, it should be: "That's about the KIND of people we need" :)

Comment: Anhören tut sich das alles prima, aber das circa im Schiftlichen abzukürzen, ohne dass es in einem formalen Maßzusammenhang auftaucht, ist ein faux pas.

Comment: You're right. I was a little hasty and misread that sentence. Then again, however, it's OK that the last example isn't fine to my ears. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why nobody quoted the "Duden" which was the "only" official resource of correct German during my school time.

> (bei Maß-, Mengen- und Zeitangaben) ungefähr, etwa; Abkürzung: ca.

Looking at most the examples given with "gleich" they all compare something. With comparison you need to use ungefaehr not circa. Circa on the other hand can be used if you give an exact numeric value but allow for "wiggle room" (so the actual value could but doesn't have to be a little bit less or more).

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention a simple use. Before numbers you can use the German word "ungefähr" or the Latin word circa meaning around and there is no difference.